# After all, it would be embarrassing when we [met/meet] again

Tags: past-tense, when

> Frieren: Himmel, you always say quick goodbyes.
>
> Himmel: You think that's strange?
>
> Eisen: It doesn't seem like you. It was just a side job. but we still
> spent two weeks traveling together.
>
> Heiter: And we drank with him practically every night.
>
> Himmel: You're right. But I'm sure we'll run into each other again if
> we continue traveling. Tearful goodbyes aren't our style. **After all,
> it would be embarrassing when we met again.**

I'd like to see if I can substitute "when we meet again" for "when we met again" in the context. If so, what's the difference between them?

Comment: We don't do text correction here. But you can try "if".

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it's not about text correction. I just introduced the context to make it possible to understand it fully. https://twitter.com/fakhrul_redza/status/1771245076162719751

Comment: It's not grammatical. It should be: when we meet again. and means have not yet met again. ""when we met again" calls for another past tense: When we met again, we were already friends"

Comment: Did you mean that "It would be embarrassing when we met again" equals "It would be embarrassing if we met again"? If so, I now understand it fully. "Met" as in if we met again expresses the action as a theoretical possibility only, something more distant from reality. "Meet" as in if we meet again expresses the action as an open possibility - we may or may not meet again. Was I clear?

Comment: I replied and saw the reply. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, if you change when to if, it's okay with the past. But otherwise, you need when we meet again in your sentence.

Comment: @avantgarde **when we met again** is used by many AmE speakers to refer to a future possibility that has a fairly good chance of happening.  As Himmel says, "I'm sure we'll run into each other again if we continue traveling".  **when we meet again** is too definite, and not synonymous.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you saved my life.

Comment: @TimR: I don't see it like that. To me, the actual *Present* Tense *...when we **meet** again* is the "definite" version (speaker is 100% certain we ***will*** meet again). On top of which, I think Present is "marked" in this exact context, since we *normally* "backshift" after things like *"It would help if you **gave** me a hand!"* (cf *"It **will** help if you **give** me a hand!"*). A "marked" version always carries some implication, and in this case the obvious candidate is the implied ***when**, not **if***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Not sure how you disagree with what I wrote. I said the present tense was "too definite and not synonymous"  [i.e. with the backshifted past tense version].